# Можно ли webview.loadurl использовать с кириллическими доменами?

Tags: android

Можно ли использовать ? если да, то как (пуникод почему-то не работает) ?

Comment: Покажите пример адреса, может неправильно формируете. Только что пробовал - работает и паникод, и непосредственно кириллица

Comment: вот адрес сайта  https://xn--90acjmnncp1a6etcf.xn--p1ai/ .
Как только вставляю - белый экран при загрузке приложения, меняю на любой другой домен латинницей - без проблем.

 `asw_view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.msw_view);

 asw_view.loadUrl(url+"?rid="+random_id());`

Comment: Может как-то дополнительно надо преобразовывать его, а не просто вставлять ? Может кодировку какую-то указать надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно этот сайт у меня тоже не открылся и проблема не в адресе. Тут что-то не так с проверкой `SSL`-сертификата и правильного решения я не знаю. Что бы это проверить добавьте в `WebViewClient` такой метод:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
        Log.w("SslError", error.toString());
    }
```

Если сайт откроется, то проблема именно с SSL - посмотрите в логах текст ошибки и задайте вопрос уже по её решению.

Comment: столько дней искал правильное решение, никто не мог дать ответа. 
А вы в точку указали . Спасибо :)